# SIlverlight: Sending serialized XML as HTTP Post

Tags: silverlight, serialization, kml

I am trying to send a KML file (which is XML) by HTTP Post to an ASPX page. This works as long as there is no escaped HTML contained in the KML.

To create the KML I use the following class for the XmlSerializer

```
public class kml
{
    [DataMember]
    public DocumentItem Document
    { get; set; }

    public kml()
    {
    }

    public class BalloonStyleItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string text
        { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string displayMode
        { get; set; }

        public BalloonStyleItem()
        {
            displayMode = "default";
        }
    }
}
   //(...)
```

In my code, that creates the KML I have this line:

```
balloonStyleItem.text = "&lt;h2&gt;name: " + substation.name + "&lt;/h2&gt;region: " + substation.Region.Region.name + "<br>subregion: " + substation.Region.name;
```

As you see it contains HTML

Now I want to send this KML by HTTP Post:

```
HttpWebRequest request = asyncResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(kml));
xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, kmlContainer);
writer.Write(xmlstring); //here it crashes!
```

At this point the execution of the program stops with the error message "WebException was unhadled by user code, The remote server returned an error: NotFound"

If I give something like

```
balloonStyleItem.text = "xxxxx";
```

(without HTML) everything works fine. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give it a try using DataContractSerializer instead of XmlSerializer? I noticed that you are using attributes designed for DataContractSerializer...

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(kml));
ser.WriteObject(stream, kmlContainer);
```